Question on Vieta's Theorem for a polynomial of degree n and the product of 2n aliquot fractions.
I need help with a problem:
Formulate and prove Vieta's theorem for a polynomial of degree n. Find the sum of products over an even number of fractions of the form
$$\frac{1}{1}, \frac{1}{2}, ..., \frac{1}{ 2n}.$$
$$n \in \mathbb{N}$$
$$ans = \frac{1}{1}\times\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{1}\times\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{3}\times\frac{1}{4} + ... + \frac{1}{1}\times\frac{1}{2}\times...\times\frac{1}{2n}$$
For example simillar problem:
For any natural n ≥ 2 solve sum:
$$\frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + ... +\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{1\times2} + \frac{1}{1\times3} + ... + \frac{1}{(n-1)\times n} + ...+\frac{1}{1\times2\times3\times...\times n}$$
to solve this porblem we can bring to a common denominator
we will get:
$$\frac{1\times2\times3\times...\times n}{1\times2\times3\times...\times n} + \frac{1\times3\times...\times n}{1\times2\times3\times...\times n} + ... +\frac{2}{1\times2\times3\times...\times n} + \frac{1}{1\times2\times3\times...\times n}$$
In the numerator we get the sum of all possible products of numbers 1, 2, 3, ..., n (including the numbers themselves)
We can show this like:
$$(1+1)(1+2)(1+3)...(1+n) - 1 = (n+1)! - 1$$
=> for this problem answeer will be:
$$\frac{(n+1)!}{n!}-1 = n$$

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

There seem to be two very different problems in your question. Please show what you did find out, maybe solve the Vieta problem first for n=2,  3, 4 to see the pattern,
